# Removing beginning of a string until the first instance of a specific character

Tags: python, regex

I have a script that compiles an .exe file and runs the `--tree=all` of that .exe. This returns the directory where the file is stored and I want to use that path to run it.

This is the output I get from `--tree=all`

`|   | +-out\windows-x86-MD-mbcs-vs2008-rel\bin\VisualStudio08-32bit.exe`

so I used the following to get rid of the special characters:

```
line = re.sub('[|+ -]', '', lines)
```

This works, but it removes all instances of `-` which results in this:

`out\windowsx86MDmbcsvs2008rel\bin\VisualStudio0832bit.exe`

But I want to get this:

`out\windows-x86-MD-mbcs-vs2008-rel\bin\VisualStudio08-32bit.exe`

How do I make sure only the first instance of `-` is removed, and the rest is left alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can rely on `-` preceding the name and you're not adamant on using a regex:

```
s = '| | +-out\windows-x86-MD-mbcs-vs2008-rel\bin\VisualStudio08-32bit.exe'
print s.split('-', 1)[1]
```

Output: `out\windows-x86-MD-mbcs-vs2008-relin\VisualStudio08-32bit.exe`

Comment: Instead of `line = re.sub('[|+ -]','',lines)` I used `line = lines.split('-',1)[1]` and that removed everything at the start!, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You will need to split the replace into two and for the second one limit the times it replaces to one.

```
line = re.sub('[|+ ]','',lines)
line = re.sub('-','',line, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.sub('^[|+ -]*', '', line)` to remove special characters at the start of the line.

Comment: This is quite a flaky solution, but should work in most cases. It may fail if the folder name starts with space or `-` or `+`.

Comment: I'm getting this error

  `File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bad character range`

Comment: Try `^[|+ -]` as the regex. I think the regex engine is interpreting `+- ` as the invalid range of characters from `+` to ` `.

Comment: The above one doesn't work, its not giving errors, but it's not removing any special characters.